# Создание объектов Image

Tags: javascript

Можно ли, когда делаешь слайд-шоу не создавать объекты Image, как показано ниже

```
 for(var i = 1; i < 11; ++i) {
    imagesFace[i] = new Image();
}
```

а просто создать массив, в котором будут хранится пути. Какой вариант лучше?

```
    for(var i = 1; i < 11; ++i) {
    imagesFace[i] = new Image();
}

imagesFace[1].src = "/images/1.jpg"
     // и так далее
imagesFace[10].src = "/images/2.jpg"

slideShowFace(imagesFace)
})

function slideShowTits(images){
   document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', nextSlide, false)

var placeSlideImg = document.getElementById('slide')

function nextSlide(event){
//...
 placeSlideImg.src = images[num].src
//...
   }
}
```

Comment: Если в Image хранятся сами пиксели картинки, то конечно лучше второй вариант, если это просто обертка над картинкой то первый вариант лучше, потому что обертка уже написана до Вас и не нужно тратить время на написание собственной.

Comment: @igumnov я не много не понял вас. У меня слайд-шоу, то есть пользователь кликает на кнопку и src меняется у самого слайда и благодаря этому появляется новая картинка. При таком подходе второй вариант лучше ?